# Need help overwriting kendo ui validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, kendo-ui

I am trying to overwrite the date validation within my code so i can validate the date as DD/MM/YYYY.
 Below is my code and i'm being shown an **`error message reading`** :

```
Unable to get property 'methods' of undefined or null reference
```

Can some please help? Im guessing the overwrite of validation code is incorrect.

```
var validator = $("#searchStartDate").kendoValidator();

var validator = $("#searchStartDate").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

 $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
                           return this.optional(element) || $.kendoDatePicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
                        }

//Picker Start Date
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#searchStartDate").kendoDatePicker({ format: "dd/MM/yyyy", culture: "en-GB" });
  });
```

Comment: Are you still having an issue with this?

Comment: Yes, i have also tried the suggestion below with no luck :(

Comment: And what happened? Did you get a different error? If you respond with a comment rather than just marking it as unhelpful it would be easier to help you. Can you add your html to the code block as well?

Comment: I got the same error. I didnt mark it down i cant mark anything up or down as i dont have enough rep. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry i am actually being displayed with this instead now, had to clear my cache. 'Unable to set property 'date' of undefined or null reference'

Comment: Okay I have setup an example on the telerik equivalent of jsfiddle and I will add it edit my answer below to show this. It shows an example of an input field with date validation in the format you need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See: http://dojo.telerik.com/OWUvU

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="myform">
<input name="myDate" class="validateDate" id="searchStartDate" /> <br />
<button>Validate</button>
</form>

<script>
$("#myform").kendoValidator({
  rules: {
    dateValidation: function(input) {
      //only validate
      if (input.hasClass('validateDate')) {
        return kendo.parseDate(input.val(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
      }
    }
  },
  messages: {
    dateValidation: "Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy"
  }
});
$("#searchStartDate").kendoDatePicker({ format: "dd/MM/yyyy", culture: "en-GB" })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above adds custom validation in the format you requested.

You were using a combination of custom jquery validation script and kendo validation.
You need to use the full kendo validation methods, see - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/validator for the full api.